# When does $ax^2 + by^2 + c z^2 = 0$ have a non-trivial solution mod $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I was wondering, is there a simple criterion for the coefficients $(a,b,c)$ to know when the equation $ax^2 + by^2 + c z^2 = 0$ has a non-trivial solution mod $p$? Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: When $a+b+c = 0 \mod p$

Comment: Is $p$ prime? If so then the answer is "always".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes $p$ is prime. Could you possibly elaborate on that little more by any chance?

Comment: Currently, the question is a bit silly - $x=y=z=0$ works for all $p$. If you are curious about solutions when not all of $x,y,z$ are zero, you should update the question to include this.

Comment: @KReiser O, yes. Of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation always has a solution.

If any of $a,b,c$ are zero, then we can easily find a solution.  For instance, if $c = 0$, then $(0,0,1)$ is solution.  So assume $a,b,c$ are all nonzero.  We will show there is a solution by counting.  There are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ nonzero squares in $\mathbb{F}_p$ and since multiplication by $a$ is a bijection, then $A = \{a x^2 : x \in \mathbb{F}_p\}$ contains $\frac{p+1}{2}$ elements (including $0$, now).  Similarly, the set $B = \{-by^2 - c : y \in \mathbb{F}_p\}$ contains $\frac{p+1}{2}$ as well.  Since $\mathbb{F}_p$ only contains $p$ elements, then there must be some overlap, i.e., $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$.  Thus there exist $x,y \in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that $ax^2 = -b y^2 - c$, so $ax^2 + by^2 + c = 0$, hence $(x,y,1)$ is a solution to your equation.  By completing the square and doing a little algebra, one can use this result to show that every conic over a finite field has a (rational) point.

As a note, by dividing your equation through by $-c$, we can instead consider solutions to the equation
\begin{align} \label{hilbert}
a x^2 + b y^2 = z^2 \, . \tag{1}
\end{align}
Just as the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ describes when the equation $x^2 = a$ has a solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$, the [Hilbert symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol) $(a,b)_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ describes when (\ref{hilbert}) has a solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$.  The Hilbert symbol determines whether the quaternion algebra given by $i^2 = a$, $j^2 = b$ is split or ramified, so [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019481/quaternion-algebras-over-finite-fields-up-to-isomorphism/2039825#2039825) gives a (much more convoluted) proof using quaternion algebras that your equation always has a solution.